# Vue.js - Prerender plugin

Tags: vue.js, prerender

I would like to use this [plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin). To prerender some of my `vue.js` components.

The structure of my project is the one coming with `Laravel 5.4`

```
├── app
├── artisan
├── bootstrap
├── resources
    ├── assets
        js
        app.js
        bootstrap.js
        components
webpackconfig.js
```

My components are located in `components`

I added this in my `webpackconfig.js` to try to render the component linked to the `/` route.

```
new PrerenderSpaPlugin(path.join(__dirname, './dist'), [ '/' ]),
```

#### Problem

The file index.html which is generated contains `{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}`

#### Questions

What should I do to be able to pre-render my components ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation sample. You are using a wrong path, Use `../dist` instead of `./dist`

```
new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
    // Path to compiled app
    path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    // List of endpoints you wish to prerender
   [ '/' ]
)
```

https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/prerender.html

Answer (score 0):

You should target the correct path for your `index.html` entry point.
You are currently targeting the `dist` folder.